# Open book on any closed oriented 3-manifold

Tags: differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology, fibration, contact-topology

I am reading "Lectures on Open Book Decompositions and Contact Structures" by Etnyre. In that paper Etnyre proves existence of open books on closed oriented 3-manifolds by using two lemma's of Alexander.

First lemma of Alexander states that for any closed oriented 3-manifold M, there exists a branched cover $P:M\longrightarrow S^3$ with a branched $L_M$ where $L_M$ is a link. The other one states that any link can be braided about unknot i.e. if U denotes the unknot, taking $S^3/U\cong S^1\times\mathbb{D}^2$, $L_M$ can be isotoped such that $L_M\subset S^1\times\mathbb{D}^2$ and $L_M$ is transverse to $\{p\}\times\mathbb{D}^2$ for each $p\in S^1$.

Now comes the open book I constructed. Considering the notation given above set $B=P^{-1}(U)$. Since $P$ is a covering away from $L_M$ and U is a loop in $S^3$, by homotopy lifting, $B$ is a loop in M. Therefore one can construct an open book around B as a sequence of maps:

$\alpha_1:(B\times\mathbb{D}^2)/B\cong B\times(\mathbb{D}^2/\{0\})\longrightarrow (\mathbb{D}^2/\{0\})$ which is the projection and

$\alpha_2:\mathbb{D}^2/\{0\}\longrightarrow S^1 $ with $\alpha_2(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$.

So we get B as the binding. But I do not understand what happens around $L_M$ living in $S^3/U$. Why do the fibers around $L_M$ have as B as the binding. Thank you for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Those are singular points in the image of the fiber. Since the fiber surface of $S^3\U$ intersect transversally to $L_M$. BTW $B$ may not be a loop but it can be a link as well (M is compact).

Comment: topologically the fiber is still a surface with boundary $B$. But around those points the chart looks lile $z\mapsto z^n$.

Comment: @Anubhav Mukherjee thank you for your help. But  why the transversality of $L_M$ imply singularity on fibers? Is this a theorem by Milnor or something like that?

Comment: This is not very difficult to see. First try to observe what is happening with the fiber for $S^3-U \to S^1$. In this case fibers are transversal to $L_M$. So the intersection is a discrete set of points. Now Take the pull back of one fiber in $M$. Then restriction of $P$ onto this pull back is a branched cover which branching over a finite set of point. So around those point the chart looks like $z\mapsto z^n$.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I got it, thanks!